# jquery element top

Tags: jquery

how i can alert div element reached particular top position,By default i have set top to 500 and animating towards top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#block").animate({ top: "100"}, 1500 );
```

I will move ur div[block] to top 100

Answer (score 3):

Use the `callback`.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/